# Is my model too heavy and complicated to animate?

Tags: rendering, animation

I've made a model of a combine harvester with 2.5 million verts and 1000 objects in it. What do I have to do to make it do some simple things like drive down the road and have some pieces on it turning and lifting? I am using  macbook air and when I parent all the objects to an empty and move it from one location to the next using two location keyframes the whole process takes a long time. I will never be able to render it. I tried breaking it into smaller view layers and using the compositor, but it looks like I was barking up the wrong tree.

What do people do (aside from buy better computers)?

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, why do you need so many vertices? If some parts are round, use a Subdivision Surface modifier to round them. Also, depending on your storyboard, you can use some high-poly parts for some shots, and low-poly for some others. High-poly objects will be very hard to animate or even manipulate, don't you have a low-poly version?

Comment: You could go old-school and make the maximum draw type for all or most objects to be bounding box. This is under Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display As > Bounds.

Comment: Hey Moonboots Thanks for taking time to reply to me. What do people do to make low poly versions?

Comment: Thanks Jeff for turning me on to draw types. Why iss that what people did old school? what changed?